# MySQL Insert ENUM field is left blank

Tags: mysql, enums, phpmyadmin

So i'm trying to insert data with the query below. The columns releases_isMultipack, releases_isChase, releases_hasChase and releases_isAssortment are all enum('0', '1') type. 0 and 1 represent false and true.

```sql
INSERT INTO releases (releases_uid, releases_title, releases_releaseDate, releases_boxNumber, releases_hobbyDbId, releases_isMultipack, releases_itemNumber, releases_isChase, releases_hasChase, releases_referenceUrl, releases_componentNumber, releases_isAssortment, releases_craftProductId, releases_craftComponentId) 
    VALUES ('fa4d5128-407a-4c2b-8970-99a36a72b030', 'Woodsy Owl', '2021-03-26T16:05:00-07:00', '', NULL, 0, '52390', 0, 1, 'woodsy-owl-1', '52390a', 0, 9518039, 9518035)
```

The query works fine, however just leaves the ENUM columns blank even though a value is provided in the insert statement.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between `0` and `'0'`.

Here's a demo. I get a blank if I insert `0` because that's not the value in the enum.

```
mysql> create table releases (releases_isMultipack enum('0','1'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into releases values (0);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                   |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'releases_isMultipack' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from releases;
+----------------------+
| releases_isMultipack |
+----------------------+
|                      |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But it works if I use `'0'`:

```
mysql> insert into releases values ('0');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from releases;
+----------------------+
| releases_isMultipack |
+----------------------+
|                      |
| 0                    |
+----------------------+
```